# Displacement from RGB data

Tags: modifiers

I'm looking to create a height map from a seabed scan that uses a coloured gradient to indicate the height range.

I've tried in the past converting these into greyscale, but ideally want to find a way to tell Blender the 'highest' and 'lowest' point colours, and calculate the displacement on this.

Have tried using the 'Ramp' section within the Displace modifier to set the colours, but this doesn't seem to give good results.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site! As it is, your question is already well formulated, but it would still be helpful to give more information. Maybe provide an example image of a height map that other users could use in their examples and elaborate on what you have tried and how it failed.

Comment: A height map is nothing but a black and white scale, where one end is the top height and 0 is no displacement. Note that you can split the color channels and use math nodes to set ranges or scale the data. It would help if you [edit]ed your post and added some example data and/or a source for such maps. I'm sure that the scale is something that is documented somewhere.

Comment: Hello :). If you use *Displacement node*, you can try the *Map Range node* to remap highest/lowest values for input/output. Also keep in mind the Displacement node Scale is in meters. Good luck :).